# How can I move all files to the parent folder using windows cmd command

Tags: windows, cmd, directory

For Example:

I have

- C:\Folder\Subfolder1\SubfolderA\file1.pdf
- C:\Folder\Subfolder1\SubfolderB\file2.pdf
- C:\Folder\Subfolder1\Subfolderc\file3.pdf

And I just want to have this path:

- C:\Folder\Subfolder1\SubfolderA
- C:\Folder\Subfolder1\SubfolderB
- C:\Folder\Subfolder1\Subfolderc
- C:\Folder\Subfolder1\file1.pdf
- C:\Folder\Subfolder1\file2.pdf
- C:\Folder\Subfolder1\file3.pdf

I am using Windows 7, and tried different commands in CMD, like:

`Move C:\Folder\Subfolder1\SubfolderA\*.* C:\Folder\Subfolder1\SubfolderA`

I spent almost a day exploring  different solutions to do this since I am working around thousands of files; and so impractical to do this manually.

Comment: please rewrite your question to mention language, platform you are using, and describe the task you are trying to solve using these tools. Do not forget to show what have you tried and what does not work. Otherwise your question will be downvoted to oblivion and closed.

Comment: Hi Sir, Sorry for this. I am trying to just cut all files inside a subfolder then trying to paste those files out of that folder.

Comment: Do you mean manual cut and paste ?

Comment: the files you are trying to copy, are they of same type? (like .exe .pdf)

Comment: No not manual copying. I would like to know if there are ways to do this using cmd?  @RafaelOsipov

Comment: No Sir @codePG, there are different file extensions inside the subfolders.

Comment: @engrshawu check the answer I have posted

Answer (score 1):

Try this command

```
for /d %A in ("D:\Shawu\Access\Main\*") do @(pushd "%A"&(for /r /d %B in (*) do @move /y "%B\*" "%A" 2>nul)&popd)
```

Be careful of files with duplicate names. It will overwrite. I would recommend you to try first with some test file to see whether you get the desired results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood you correctly, so, below there's the solution.

Imagine there are two folders:

`C:\ABC`

and `C:\ABC\XYZ`

to transfer all files from `C:\ABC\XYZ` to `C:\ABC` do the following:

1. Navigate to `C:\ABC\XYZ`
2. Execute the command: **`move *.* ..`**

and that's it.

All files from `C:\ABC\XYZ` will be moved to the parent folder, i.e to `C:\ABC\`

Below, there are pictures to demonstrate this solution.

- Folder `ABC` contains `XYZ` folder

[image: folder ABC contains XYZ folder]

- we navigate to `XYZ` and there are some files exist

[image: we navigate to XYZ and there are some files exist]

- We execute `move *.* ..` command to transfer files to the parent (`ABC`) folder

[image: we execute "move" command]

- now `XYZ` is empty

[image: now XYZ is empty]

And all files from `XYZ` are in `ABC` (parent folder) now

[image: and all files from XYZ are in ABC now]

Comment: Hi,

I tried  to execute this command, however it respond this message:
"The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: have you navigated to the folder where files are located ?

Comment: Yes, Actually I have this link:

D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\TssR1\File1
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\TssR1\File2
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\TssR1\File3
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\TssR1\File4
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\TssR1\File5
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\TssR1\File6
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\TssR2\File1
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\TssR2\File2
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\TssR3\File1
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\TssR4\File1

Comment: I need that to be like this:

D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\TssR1
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\TssR2
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\TssR3
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\TssR4
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\File1
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\File1 (1)
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\File1 (2)
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\File1 (3)
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\File2
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\File2 (1)
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\File3
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\File4
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\File5
D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106\File6

Comment: I Tried to navigate in cmd, 

D:\Shawu\Access\Main\NCR\MIL106> move *.*..
and this message occurs: "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

Comment: it is hard to read and understand those strings. Just for example, make `ABC` and `XYZ` folders on the `C:` disk, place some files to the `XYZ`, then navigate to `XYZ` and execute the command I mentioned in my answer. Does it work?

Comment: when you do all the steps I described in my answer (I assume you have created `ABC`, `XYZ` and navigated to `XYZ` before executing the command), what error do you get? Make a screenshot, upload it to imgur.com and give me a link to it.