# Move files to parent folder in CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, dos, move

I need a sanity check. I remember being able to run a command like this:

```
C:\TestFolder> move *.* ..
```

This should move all files in the current folder up one folder, ie. to the parent.

Running this now, in a Windows 10 command prompt, I get the following error:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I've looked through a bunch of similar questions at StackOverflow. Most answers say that some complex loop command is required to move files to the parent. Those that mention `move *.* ..` have some people saying this command works for them, while others report the same error I'm getting.

One example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25542277/2066896 (expand all comments to see the relevant exchange)

Granted, I haven't needed to use this command in years, so perhaps support for the ".." notation in the move command was removed at some point in Windows' recent history. Or perhaps it was never there, and I'm just dreaming.

Just wondering if someone can clear this up. Thanks!

Comment: It works in Windows 8.1 32 bit.  I'd be surprised if it failed in Windows X if you have write permissions to the parent folder - there are reasons why commands fail (batch files/extra executables with the same name) and a screen shot will give further clarification.

Comment: It works in Windows 8.1 64 bit as well. Try `move \*.\* ..\\` with trailing backslash.

Comment: I tried it again after reading these comments and it suddenly started working. I have no idea what was wrong before... I must be losing my mind. It seems to work now with or without the trailing backslash. Thank you for the comments and sorry for wasting time...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The  error appears if there is nothing to move, see an example below. Try

```
move *.* .. 2>NUL
```

**Example**:

```
D:\test\a folder\with spaces>move *.* ..
D:\test\a folder\with spaces\New Text Document (2).txt
D:\test\a folder\with spaces\New Text Document.txt
        2 file(s) moved.

D:\test\a folder\with spaces>move *.* ..
The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect.

D:\test\a folder\with spaces>move *.* .. 2>NUL

D:\test\a folder\with spaces>
```